# asp.net chart control value label position

Tags: asp.net, charts

I am displaying data in asp.net chart control. Using a 3d bar chart. I am showing the values next to the bars. (seriesCount.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;). The chart control is rendering the value label still on top of the bar and is making the value hard to read. I am trying to position this label to the right but so far I've found no way to do it. I've also tried enabling Smart labels hoping and putting a marker on the bar to push the value away but I haven't been successful. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Sample code:

```
Chart chartSubjects = new Chart();
chartSubjects.Width = Unit.Pixel(800);
chartSubjects.Height = Unit.Pixel(300);
chartSubjects.AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.All;

Series seriesCount = new Series("subjectsCountSeries");
seriesCount.YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
seriesCount.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
seriesCount.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
seriesCount.ChartArea = "subjectsCountArea";
chartSubjects.Series.Add(seriesCount);

ChartArea areaCount = new ChartArea("subjectsCountArea");
LabelStyle yAxisStyle = new LabelStyle();
yAxisStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#444444");
yAxisStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 11, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
areaCount.AxisY.LabelStyle = yAxisStyle;
areaCount.AxisY.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
areaCount.Position.Width = 50;
areaCount.Position.Height = 100;
areaCount.Position.X = 0;
areaCount.Position.Y = 0;
areaCount.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
areaCount.Area3DStyle.LightStyle = LightStyle.Realistic;
areaCount.Area3DStyle.WallWidth = 4;
areaCount.Area3DStyle.Inclination = 10;
areaCount.Area3DStyle.Perspective = 10;
areaCount.Area3DStyle.Rotation = 20;
areaCount.Area3DStyle.PointDepth = 90;
chartSubjects.ChartAreas.Add(areaCount);

int[] pointsToAdd = new int[] { 1434, 712, 601, 204, 173, 168, 64, 35, 22, 8, 2 };
foreach (int point in pointsToAdd)
{
    DataPoint dataPoint = new DataPoint();
    dataPoint.SetValueY(point);
    seriesCount.Points.Add(dataPoint);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Post some code that illustrates the problem you are having.

Comment: seriesCount.MarkerColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
    seriesCount.MarkerSize = 16;
    seriesCount.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Square;
    seriesCount.SmartLabelStyle.MinMovingDistance = 10;
    seriesCount.SmartLabelStyle.AllowOutsidePlotArea = LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.Yes;
    seriesCount.SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = true;
    seriesCount.SmartLabelStyle.MovingDirection = LabelAlignmentStyles.Right;

Comment: The previous code was my first attempt to solve the problem. Eventually I realized that I was missing a crucial piece of code: seriesCount.SmartLabelStyle.IsMarkerOverlappingAllowed = false; This effectively pushed the value label to the right in all but the first bar (pushed left away from the transparent marker).

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Bar" 
            CustomProperties="BarLabelStyle=Right" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" 
            Palette="EarthTones" XValueMember="xvalue" YValueMembers="yvalue">
</asp:Series>
```

`CustomProperties="BarLabelStyle=Right"` did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I'd use:

```
chartSubjects.Series["seriesCount"]["LabelStyle"] = "Right";
```